# How to populate count/sum of certain fields (Number datatype) in a custom object?

Tags: trigger, custom-object, master-detail, roll-up-summary

Custom object "A" should have certain fields like "Number of Contacts with training date" and "Number of Contacts Last Trained". Currently "A" has look-up relationship with Contacts for the other fields such as "Primary Contact" etc. How does the count/sum of the number in fields "Number of Contacts" and "Number of Contacts Last Trained" of Custom object "A" gets populated? There is no field on Contact which indicates if the contact is trained or no field to get total number of contacts. In that case, should I create a field on "Contact" first? Is this requirement possible with roll-up summary or trigger? If roll-up summary then "A" has to be a master object but it is not a master object. Please help me with this.

Edited for extra info:Custom object "A" should look up to "count of related Contacts with training date" and "count of related contacts with last trained date".

Comment: The generalized answer is [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), but the data model you've articulated doesn't really make sense. Could you [edit] to make very clear which object looks up to which, and where the data that is being rolled. up is located?

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks for quick response! I have edited my question. I am guessing if "Contact" object should have those fields first before we count/sum it to custom object "A"? Just figuring out the flow. Sorry, I am a newbie.

Comment: Where is the relationship (lookup) field located?

Comment: @DavidReed There is no look up field created as such but the requirement is Custom Object "A"  has to look up to Contacts. There is no field on Contact that indicates whether contact is trained or no field to get total number of contacts. It says Custom Object "A" should have fields "Number of Contacts with training date" and "Number of Contacts Last Trained" which are lookups to Contact. Should I go ahead and create some fields on Contact first?

Comment: That data model doesn't make sense. If A looks up to Contact, A is the child. You don't roll up data to children from parents.